# libqt5core5a dependency/version conflict in 16.04

Tags: apt, dependencies

I'm  getting the same ***libqt5core5a*** **dependency problem** trying to install both *OnionShare* (version 0.9.1-1 from *deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu xenial main*) and *Calibre*, in Ubuntu-MATE 16.04:

```
--> sudo aptitude install onionshare
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5designer5{ab} onionshare python3-pyqt5{ab} python3-sip{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,961 kB of archives. After unpacking 20.5 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:   
              - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-2~xenial+build2 is installed. 
libqt5designer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:   
              - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-2~xenial+build2 is installed. 
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libqt5designer5 [Not Installed]                    
2)     onionshare [Not Installed]                         
3)     python3-pyqt5 [Not Installed]                      

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

(I get the same message as above when I try to install Calibre.)

```
--> apt-cache policy libqt5core5a  
libqt5core5a:
  Installed: 5.6.1+dfsg-2~xenial+build2
  Candidate: 5.6.1+dfsg-2~xenial+build2
  Version table:
*** 5.6.1+dfsg-2~xenial+build2 100
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 500
       500 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
    5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 500
       500 http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Also:

```
--> sudo aptitude -f install libqt5core5a
libqt5core5a is already installed at the requested version(5.6.1+dfsg-2~xenial+build2)
```

Two other (perhaps relevant) libraries ( ***libqt5gui5*** and ***libqt5opengl5*** ) are installed in addition to ***libqt5core5a***.  All three of them are at version *5.6.1+dfsg-2~xenial+build2*.

But the following (also perhaps relevant) libraries are **not** installed, and all of *these* appear in Synaptic at version *5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu6* :

***libqt5gui5-gles

libqt5opengl5-gles

libqt5opengl5-gles-dev

libqt5opengl5-dev

libqt5network5***

Naturally, I'm reluctant to do anything with ***libqt5core5a*** until I know what I'm doing, since, as the name ***core*** suggests, this library affects a ton of other packages.

Should I try to find the *5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1*  version, install it & then remove the 5.6.1?

(Not sure where I'd find it, though, since version *5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu6* is not in Synaptic, and I already have (in /etc/apt/sources.list) both of the "500" repos that are listed under the

```
apt-cache policy libqt5core5a
```

command above (or at least I think I do):

```
deb http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive/ xenial-updates restricted main
```

and

```
deb http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive/ xenial restricted main
```

(*Onionshare*, btw, installed with no problems in MATE-14.04. The developr said it should work with any version of Qt5.)

*Basically, I'm asking:* ***How should this conflict be resolved?***

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly if i'm doing it right, but this seems works for me:

```
sudo apt install libqt5core5a:i386
```